# Creating USB with 3 partition fails

Tags: usb, mac

I followed this guide http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx to create a bootable USB Stick using OS X Mavericks. I created 3 partitions on the USB stick. I converted the .iso file to .dmg and copied it to one of the partitions with *sudo dd*.
Everything seemed to be working but when I start my Mac I can't select the USB drive to boot from it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

***Don't create 3 partitions***.creating only one partition will ensure that correct partition is booted(as there will be only one partition)

Comment: Great! Now it works!

Comment: if it works,consider accepting the question(click on tick mark below the upvotes in answer)